# Abstract Class PayCalulator -Code

Tags: java, abstract

Create an abstract class PayCalculator that has an attribute payRate given in
dollars per hour. The class should also have a method computePay(hours)
that returns the pay for a given amount of time.

Can someone give me a jump start or skelatal outline on how to start and finish this?

EDIT: So far this is my code.

```
     package Main;

abstract class PayCalulator  {
    public static void main(String args[]){
     double payRate;
     int hoursWorked;
     int daysWorked;


     payRate = 12.75;
     hoursWorked = 14;
     daysWorked = 5;
     System.out.println("Here is your the break down of your pay in dollars is : " + hoursWorked * payRate);
     System.out.println("Total pay for a weeks worth of work is : " + hoursWorked * payRate * daysWorked);
     System.out.println("Please insert your hourly pay, how many hours you have worked and total pay expeted into the respective programming areas.");  

    }

}
```

Comment: It's pretty deep into the semester to be this lost... what have you tried so far?  What are you not grasping?  BTW, an abstract class essentially IS a skelatal outline...

Comment: I am lost because I do not understand methods and how to use classes with accessor and mutator methods. I have tried to refer to textbooks and teacher help but I can't seem to grasp the material.

Comment: If you are this completely lost and have no idea where to even begin and you're this far into the class, you desperately need to talk to your professor immediately.  I don't know about you, but where I'm attending, Friday is the last possible day to drop a class.

Comment: I taking this class as a challenge. So I still want to stick with it.

Comment: That's fine... but we're pretty far into the semester and you're absolutely clueless on one of `Java`'s basic concepts.  You need to talk with your teacher.  I'm not telling you to drop.  I'm telling you to get some help from your teacher or perhaps classmates.

Comment: Ok sure Ill look in to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand what an abstract class implies in java before you attempt this. If you don't, you can read about here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html, but basically the code would look like this:

```
public abstract class PayCalculator{
double payRate; //implement dollars per hour
abstract double computePay(int hours);
}
```

In the future, I'd recommend having some idea of how to approach a problem before asking Stackoverflow to supply you with all the code.